# XML PHP, filter out specific "type"

Tags: php, xml

I'm extracting the required nodes from the api easily from the response here : https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/fc02b10c-8a09-38d6-b612-22c47794d2c6?inc=releases+media+url-rels

However, i am trying to get the target of relation type discogs from the below with no luck, any help appreciated

```
<relation-list target-type="url">
    <relation type-id="6578f0e9-1ace-4095-9de8-6e517ddb1ceb" type="wikipedia">
        <target id="cba6f347-45b3-4bd5-8b7f-818fa76a63b2">
            http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insineratehymn
        </target>
    </relation>
    <relation type-id="99e550f3-5ab4-3110-b5b9-fe01d970b126" type="discogs">
        <target id="e9e6e840-ca1a-47fa-b835-47d0d86bcda8">
            http://www.discogs.com/master/316106
       </target>
    </relation>
    <relation type-id="b988d08c-5d86-4a57-9557-c83b399e3580" type="wikidata">
        <target id="f9b00d41-6f25-4174-9c72-ba1c452cfa6d">
            http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1932481
        </target>
    </relation>
</relation-list>
```

Comment: You tagged the question JSON, but this is XML.

Comment: There is lib to access to XML, with Xpath or by converting it to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made a simple code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/fc02b10c-8a09-38d6-b612-22c47794d2c6?inc=releases+media+url-rels');
foreach($xml->{'release-group'}->{'relation-list'}->relation as $relation) {
    if($relation['type'] == 'discogs') {
        $link = $relation->target;
    }
}

echo $link;
```

Output:

```
http://www.discogs.com/master/316106
```

Comment: This is copied content

Comment: @Doomish This is copied content

Comment: Nothing was copied, sir.

Comment: @Doomish do you run this code. Check this  link http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81acefc1d2da91338e54536f0c3bc2b180badaa4

Comment: check my link and execute your code. given url is https secure server URL.

Comment: do you know simplexml_load_file not scrapping the https urls?

Comment: Sure it does! The webserver have to enable `php_openssl`. And it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
    <?php
$url = 'https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/fc02b10c-8a09-38d6-b612-22c47794d2c6?inc=releases+media+url-rels';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$res = simplexml_load_string($result);
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($res);
$listing = $res->{'release-group'}->{'relation-list'}->relation;

// full listing  
foreach($listing as $list)
{
    echo $list['type']."<br>"; // full listing       
}

//Particular url
foreach($listing as $list)
{
    if($list['type'] == 'discogs') 
    {
        echo $list->target; // Particular url
    }        
}


exit;
```

**Output**

```
wikipedia
discogs
wikidata


http://www.discogs.com/master/316106
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, i can loop fine, however i only want to extract/display the "relation" of type "discogs"

Comment: the OP said this particular relation tag `<relation type-id="99e550f3-5ab4-3110-b5b9-fe01d970b126" type="discogs">` type="discogs"

Comment: @Nathan-Srivi in the loop you provided,i want ONLY the discogs.com link

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->attributes()` method to check whether that particular tag contains the desired attribute that you want. Example:

```
// without xpath
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/fc02b10c-8a09-38d6-b612-22c47794d2c6?inc=releases+media+url-rels');
foreach($xml->{'release-group'}->{'relation-list'}->{'relation'} as $relation) {
    if($relation->attributes()['type'] == 'discogs') { // dereference (5.4 or above)
        echo (string) $relation->target; // http://www.discogs.com/master/316106
    }
}
```

Or you can also use xpath and register the namespace inside the xml, and target it directly:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('r', 'http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#'); // registers xmlns (namespace)
$discogs = (string) $xml->xpath('//r:release-group/r:relation-list/r:relation[@type="discogs"]/r:target')[0];
echo $discogs; // http://www.discogs.com/master/316106
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML uses a namespace. DOM+Xpath allows you to take this in account and to fetch the string value directly:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load(
  'https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/fc02b10c-8a09-38d6-b612-22c47794d2c6?inc=releases+media+url-rels'
);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('mb', "http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#");

$expression = 'string(
  //mb:release-group
  /mb:relation-list
  /mb:relation[@type = "discogs"]
  /mb:target
)';

var_dump($xpath->evaluate($expression));
```

Output:

```
string(36) "http://www.discogs.com/master/316106"
```